# Can I Bulk Import Collections into an Insomnia project?

Tags: insomnia

I'm currently setting up my API testing environment in Insomnia and I have a number of collections that I need to import.
I've checked the Insomnia documentation and GUI options, but I haven't found a way to import multiple collections at once into an empty dashboard.